# Equality of records with members whose types are dependent (Lean 4)

Tags: type-theory, lean4

(Previously, I [asked](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/1740/1695)
about converting a term `a: A` to a term of type `B` provided that `A = B`.
Apologies if this turns out to be (about) the same issue, but I am convinced
it's a different one.)

Let's say we have a structure like this (the latter example is included
for completeness, but I am mainly interested in the propositional case
if it makes any difference).

```
-- Example with a proposition
structure Interval where
  lower: Nat
  upper: Nat
  lu: lower ≤ upper

-- Example with a function
structure Signature :=
  symbol : Type
  arity : symbol → Type
```

**Problem**: I would like to prove that for any two intervals `a` and `b`,
if `a.lower = b.lower` and `a.upper = b.upper`, then `a = b`.
(For instance to later define a pointwise partial order
on intervals, and prove that it's antisymmetric.)

As long as the structure contains no members whose types are dependent,
this is a simple matter:

```
structure PreInterval where
  lower: Nat
  upper: Nat

def PreInterval.eq
  (a b: PreInterval)
  (lEq: a.lower = b.lower)
  (uEq: a.upper = b.upper)
:
  a = b
:=
  -- (Can this be done in fewer steps/without the middleman?)
  let aMid: a = ⟨b.lower, b.upper⟩ := lEq ▸ uEq ▸ rfl;
  let midB: ⟨b.lower, b.upper⟩ = b := rfl;
  Eq.trans aMid midB
```

However, this approach fails for members of dependent types (like `lu`),
because their equality cannot be even stated (trying so
produces a "type mismatch" error, since they are of different
types).

Applying the trick from the previous question does not seem to be of help,
because it seems to me I don't need to convert one value into a value of the
other type, I need to show that they are equal, despite that they have
different types. (Or not?)

Is this possible? Or should I be doing something else?

---

**Subquestion**, if anybody knows the history:

I've looked around, and it seems to me that in Lean 2, there was
the concept of heterogenous equality, exactly for this purpose.
It allowed generalizing `congr` for dependent types, and could even
be turned into a proof of regular equality! (Ctrl+F "heq.to_eq"
[here](https://github.com/leanprover/tutorial/blob/master/06_Inductive_Types.org))

However, the only mention of heterogenous equality in Lean 4 that
I found was in the tutorial [chapter 7](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/inductive_types.html),
which says it will be introduced in the next chapter, but it is not.
The source of Lean 4's Prelude [warns against using it](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/master/src/Init/Prelude.lean#L438),
and `heq.to_eq` seems to not exist anymore. *What happended to `heq`?*

Comment: For completeness, I am leaving a [link](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1572718466838433792) here that contains an answer to the function case in the replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple.  I'll give you a few options so you can learn more about Lean.

A brute force way to do it is to use `calc`.  I know I taught you last time about `▸` but in your proof of `PreInterval.eq` since it is purely equational reasoning, you can just use `calc` for a straightforward and easy to read proof.

```
theorem Interval.eq_calc_proof
  (a b: Interval)
  (lEq: a.lower = b.lower)
  (uEq: a.upper = b.upper)
: a = b := calc
    a = ⟨ a.lower, a.upper, a.lu ⟩ := rfl
    _ = ⟨ b.lower, b.upper, b.lu ⟩ := by simp [lEq, uEq]
    _ = b := rfl
```

Notice the important thing is to solve `⟨ a.lower, a.upper, a.lu ⟩ = ⟨ b.lower, b.upper, b.lu ⟩` and the `simp` tactic is smart enough to solve this.

A very useful thing to understand about structures is that ultimately every property about structures and inductives come from their eliminator/recursor, in this case `Interval.rec`.  While I don't encourage you to use it directly, knowing it exists helps.  One way `rec` is used implicitely is in tactics and tools which let you work with inductives, like `match`, `induction`, and `cases`.  (A structure is basically an inductive with one constructor `mk`.)  By applying the `cases` tactic, we are reducing a structure to talking about the stuff *inside the structure*.

```
theorem Interval.eq_cases_proof
  (a b: Interval)
  (lEq: a.lower = b.lower)
  (uEq: a.upper = b.upper)
: a = b := by
  cases a
  cases b
  simp [lEq, uEq]
```

It may also help to see what is internally going on by using the more explicit version of the `cases` tactic:

```
theorem Interval.eq_cases_proof2
  (a b: Interval)
  (lEq: a.lower = b.lower)
  (uEq: a.upper = b.upper)
: a = b := by
  cases a with 
  | mk al au aul =>
    cases b with
    | mk bl bu bul =>
      simp [lEq, uEq]
```

Also along with the eliminator/recursor `Interval.rec`, Lean automatically generates a few helper theorems for each structure, including the following one.  (In Lean 3 it is a bit easier to find these theorems.  You can just type `#print Interval.` and Lean's autocomplete will fill in all possible completions after the projection dot `.`.  Lean 4 doesn't have this yet.)  See [this answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1664/122) for explanation about these automatic theorems and more about `rec`.

```
#check Interval.mk.injEq
-- Interval.mk.injEq :
-- ∀ (lower upper : Nat) (lu : lower ≤ upper)
--   (lower_1 upper_1 : Nat) (lu_1 : lower_1 ≤ upper_1),
-- ({ lower := lower, upper := upper, lu := lu } = 
--  { lower := lower_1, upper := upper_1, lu := lu_1 }) =
-- (lower = lower_1 ∧ upper = upper_1)
```

This theorem may be good enough for your purposes, but if not, you can easily use it to prove your lemma rewriting your goal with it:

```
theorem Interval.eq_injEq_proof
  (a b: Interval)
  (lEq: a.lower = b.lower)
  (uEq: a.upper = b.upper)
: a = b := by
  rw [Interval.mk.injEq]
  exact ⟨lEq, uEq⟩
```

(Note, all these proofs use the `propext` axiom which is used freely in Lean, even at the lowest levels.  <strike>I believe this theorem requires it because you require that the proof of `a.lu` is equal to the proof of `b.lu` without giving that as an assumption.</strike>  [Edit: I checked in Lean 3, which isn't so aggressive with `propext` and I can construct a proof with no extra axioms, besides proof irrelevance, which is built into the definitional equality rules of Lean's `Prop`.])

Answer (score 2):

This is a very slick solution that I use all the time:

```
structure Interval where
  lower: Nat
  upper: Nat
  lu: lower ≤ upper

protected theorem Interval.eq : ∀ {a b : Interval}, a.lower = b.lower → a.upper = b.upper → a = b
| ⟨_,_,_⟩, ⟨_,_,_⟩, rfl, rfl => rfl
```

Maybe it's a bit too slick since it relies on the fact that structures have only one constructor and so does equality.

In tactic mode, the equivalent is this:

```
protected theorem Interval.eq' {a b : Interval} (hl : a.lower = b.lower) (hu : a.upper = b.upper) : a = b := by
  cases a
  cases b
  cases hl
  cases hu
  rfl
```

This version is a bit longer but it allows you to follow the reasoning step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way of reproducing your error is this snippet, using `×` as the simplest "dependent record type":

```
def SigmaEq {α : Type u} (β : α → Type v)
  (a b : (x : α) × (β x)) :=
  (a.1 = b.1) ∧ (a.2 = b.2)
```

Lean4 thinks that `a.2` and `b.2` does not have the same type:

```
type mismatch
  b.snd
has type
  β b.fst : Type v
but is expected to have type
  β a.fst : Type v
```

And this quite understandable, because they indeed have different types. However, since we already have a proof `p : a.1 = b.1`, we can *cast* using this type:

```
theorem Eq.coe {α : Sort u} {P : α → Type v} {a b : α} (h₁ : Eq a b) (h₂ : P a) : P b :=
  Eq.ndrec h₂ h₁

def SigmaEq {α : Type u} (β : α → Type v)
  (a b : (x : α) × (β x)) :=
  (p : a.1 = b.1) ×' (p.coe a.2 = b.2)
```

(I've tried to use `ndrec` and `subst` directly, but `subst` seems to be only about propositions, and `ndrec` gives me strange error).

To construct something of type `SigmaEq`, we first construct the proof `p : a.1 = a.2`, then destruct `p` so that the type of `a.2` becomes `P b.1` instead of the original `P a.1`.

P.S. using heterogeneous equality is an overkill on the theory side *and* user experience side. The usual equality helps type inference: if you have `a = b` and you know the type of `a`, Lean can figure out the type of `b`. If it's heterogeneous, both sides should have their types known in advance. This may lead to extra type annotations and inconveniences. I also personally hate heterogeneous equality because it assumes axiom K in its elimination, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it leaves me very confused. How does constructing the pair of propositions `(p : a.1 = b.1) ×' (p.coe a.2 = b.2)` help me with proving that `a = b`? (Perhaps my question had a confusing wording, so I edited it to make it clearer.)

Comment: Oh, and if you meant to suggest to me to use SigmaEq instead of Eq, then I think I have a problem, because I need Eq to prove for example the antisymmetry of a partial order, which is stated as `a ≤ b → b ≤ a → a = b`, not `a ≤ b → b ≤ a → SigmaEq a b`. So I'm not sure SigmaEq can help me. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's main question.  (It might address the side question about `HEq` though.)  It might be that if @ice1000 doesn't want to use axiom K, then in their mind this theorem is unprovable as asked.

Comment: (My last Axiom K comment was a bit misguided.  I think the asked for theorem would hold even in settings where axiom K was false like Univalent foundations.  I think all one needs is proof irrelevance, which is baked into Lean's `Prop` and Coq's `SProp`.  But it is possible I'm mistaken.  Anyway, as my answer shows it is provable in Lean within Lean's base logic and propositional extensionality.)